# How to prevent jQuery UI change HTML elements with `draggable` attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wMGbYv. As you can see, jQuery UI discards `draggable` attribute and adds it's own classes. How to prevent this naughtiness and create element with `draggable` attribute without discarding jQuery UI (preferably using jQuery)?

Comment: Why do you want to do so ? They mus be using `$('[draggable]')` selector to apply classes and draggable behavior. Don;t you want those elements to be draggable ?

Comment: I need to use browser draggable API because it allows interapplicational drag'n'drop. jQuery UI doesn't.

Comment: Give it a try: `$(".tooltip").draggable({ disabled: true });`

Comment: @RayonDabre, it disables jQuery UI functionality but doesn't return default.

Comment: Can you show us a small demo ? That would help! May be after disabling it, you need to assign attribute again...Just a blind shot...

Comment: @RayonDabre, http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wMGbYv. Open browser console and you can see that created element doesn't have `draggable` attribute.

Comment: I saw that but I am asking for a demo where one can make changes and try it out...

Comment: @RayonDabre, it was enough for me. Anyway, I've found the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
$( '<div/>' ).prop( 'draggable', true )
```

Instead of `$( '<div/>', { draggable: true } )`. Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/adNrPq.